# Python: Dict get method always throws exception if the default is set to a function which throws exception

Tags: python, exception, dictionary, data-structures, default

In get method if my default function has an exception, then the control always go to the default function irrespective of the key present or not in dictionary. Here is the code block which demonstrate the same.
Compiler details are as follows :
Python 2.7.6 (default, Apr  8 2015, 11:18:18) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2

```
abc = 1
bcd = 2
class a(object):
    def test1(self):
        alphaNumMap = {
                    'a':abc,
                    'b':bcd
                    }
        num = alphaNumMap.get("a", self.add())
        print num


    def add(self):
        print "add called "
        raise Exception

if __name__ == "__main__":
    A = a()
    A.test1()
```

output of the above code is follows :

```
add called 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 19, in <module>
A.test1()
File "test2.py", line 10, in test1
ipXpath = alphaNumMap.get("a",self.add())
File "test2.py", line 15, in add
raise Exception 
Exception
```

While the expected output is 1 , because 'a' is present in the dict alphaNumMap

Answer (score 2):

Certainly it raises exception.

*Any* function invocation (in your case, `alphaNumMap.get("a",self.add())`) has to evaluate all its arguments first, *prior to pass control to the function*. So, `add()` is called, the exception is raised, and `get()` isn't called at all.

The simplest way would be to assign a default (exceptional) value and then check for it:

```
ipXpath = alphaNumMap.get("a", None) # instead of None there could be
if ipXpath is None:                  # An_exceptional_value_specific_to_your_program
    ipXpath = self.add()
```

The expression can be shorter (a oneliner) but the whole idea remains intact

Comment: It may be worth noting that the `add()` function is called by the interpreter while preparing `get`'s arguments, and `get` never even starts running before the exception derails things. You can see this in the traceback, it goes right from `test1` to `add` without any mention of `get`'s frame.

Answer (score 1):

`.get` will evaluate the default value first, regardless of whether the key was found or not. To get around this do something like: `x=d.get(key)` and then `if x is None: do stuff`.

`.get` is simply another function that just happens to belong to a dictionary. As with any other function in python, all the arguments need to be evaluated before the function gets executed. One of those arguments is `self.add()` which ends up throwing an exception when getting evaluated.

For example:

```
>>> d = {1: 2}
# Throws a NameError - fn is undefined
>>> d.get(1, fn())
# Prints 2 (here you need to be careful with the or - anything that evaluates to a False (in a boolean sense) will end up causing fn() to execute - maybe compare to a None, which is what get would have return for a missing key.
>>> d.get(1) or fn() # Careful with the or here, alternative approach below
>>> x = d.get(1)
>>> y = x if x is not None else fn()
```

Comment: Is there a reason for it behaving that way?

Comment: So  we can't have a function call in get method as default. Since the evaluation of the parameters are prior to get method evaluation. @BAH

Comment: @user700110 yes, if you don't want that function getting evaluated if the key was found, you can't put it inside get